# In Javascript, is it possible to require() a module into the current scope, instead of an object?

Tags: javascript

So for instance, 
Could you, instead of this,

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile( ... );
```

Do this?

```
??? require('fs') ???;
writeFile( ... );
```

Comment: Explicit namespace naming is such a huge improvement over implicit namespace imports that other languages such as Go have implemented their imports in a similar way (though in Go's case it's optional). Why would you want to go backwards 30 years?

Comment: syntactical cleanliness.  or minimalism.  i know ahead of time there won't be any name collisions.

Comment: Minimalism maybe but to me that's the exact opposite of syntactical cleanliness.

Comment: Symbols and punctuation pile up and obscure the core of what you're trying to do, requiring more comments to compensate for it.  I had enough; I'm transitioning to Coffeescript and couldn't be happier.  Trying to maximize simplicity.  If you keep your code small and simple enough so that you don't need to (always) rely on enforced namespace qualifiers ... it's an advantage.  Trust me.

To clarify more, I take the meaning of "code cleanliness" as literally as you can; fewer extraneous details = cleaner.  Most people seem to consider "cleanliness" a synonym with "precision"... or "safety"